# how to convert c written code in Python

Tags: python, c, bittorrent

Can someone explain what is exactly happening in this code so I can write it in python. 
I need to follow exactly the same c written specification so later on this part will be implemented in python bloom filters for Bep33 bit torrent DHT

```
//fixed parameters
 k = 2

 m = 256*8

 //the filter
byte[m/8] bloom   ## 

function insertIP(byte[] ip) {

byte[20] hash = sha1(ip)

int index1 = hash[0] | hash[1] << 8 # how to in python?
int index2 = hash[2] | hash[3] << 8

// truncate index to m (11 bits required)
index1 %= m  ## ?
index2 %= m  ## ?

// set bits at index1 and index2
 bloom[index1 / 8] |= 0x01 << index1 % 8   ## ??
 bloom[index2 / 8] |= 0x01 << index2 % 8   ## ??
 }

// insert IP 192.168.1.1 into the filter:
   insertIP(byte[4] {192,168,1,1})
```

I am trying to convert it to python see comments below

```
 import hashlib
 import socket
 import struct
 class blommy(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.bitarray= [0]*2048

     def hashes(self,ip):
         #convert decimal dotted quad string to long integer"
         intip= struct.unpack('>L',socket.inet_aton(ip))[0] #>converting stringt to int
         index = [0, 1]
         hbyte = hashlib.sha1(intip) # # #sha1 doesnt accept int ? what needs to be done?
         index[0] = ord(hbyte[0])| ord(hbyte[1])<< 8 
         index[1] = ord(hbyte[2])| ord(hbyte[3])<< 8
         # how do i shift the bits?
```

Comment: What are the C# and JavaScript tags doing there?

Comment: @alexn probbaly the original code is C#, not C, see e.g. array type syntax (though it is not real C# either)

Comment: No matters even if the original code is in c#,c etc question was to understanding logic as I mentioned it is for DHT.

Answer (score 2):

sha1 accepts normal string in Python 2.x. You may need individual bytes directly from socket.inet_aton(ip) (not sure if the order is right for your algorithm)

As for bit shifts, I think Python has the same syntax, but you may need to add parentheses if in doubt about the execution order.

Also, C char can act as int, but in Python you need to always explicitly convert between them by using ord() and chr() functions.

Even things like `%=`  and `|=` will work in Python.